# Aggregating elements which ids are recursively stored in nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is an object that stores ids of elements recursively. Each array has an `elementId` and a nested collection of the same type. Max depth of

```
myObject: {
    elementId: "jh442gd321";
    subObjects: [
        {
            elementId: "kjh34jh4y",
            subObjects: [
                {
                    elementId: "df334n35j5",
                    subObjects: [...]
                },{...}
            ]
        },{...}
    ] 
}
```

I want to search all  theses `elementId`'s in my `elements` collection using mongo aggregation framework. How can you do this without writing a `$lookup` for each nested `subOjects`?
Here is the example of how `element` looks like:

```
elements: {
    id: "jh442gd321";
    name: "my name";
    description: "short description"
}
```

Edit: my mongo shell version is 3.4